# How to store a list of numbers in a link list

Tags: c++

I have been trying to store the numbers of the array in a link list. But I don't know how to do it. I need someone to help me finish the code.

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numeros[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    typedef struct Node *NodePtr; //declara Nodeptr un apuntador a Node
    struct Node
    {
        int x;
        Node *next; // omit the 'struct' for C++-only usage
    };

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: I'm not really seeing an attempt to insert data into your link list in this code. What have you tried and what problems have you encountered?

Comment: `std::list<int>` ? and if you don't want `std`, why doing a `using namespace std` ?

Comment: If you are asking to do your homework this is no the proper site. You're asking for a complete theory argument and implementation. You should study it first, try alone and only after, in case *some* parts of code don't work, post a proper and precise question

Comment: Please learn the abstract concept of Linked Lists yourself, and also try implementing it. We have no issues with putting up the whole code, but then when will you start learning, if you keep copy-pasting? Try googling for Linked-Lists tutorials, and a metric ton of results will show up! If you learn the concept and implement it yourself, your understanding of this concept will be a long-term affair. Try your best, to learn, and if you still can't, then let us know what you've tried, and what your problem is. Good luck!

Comment: There are a lot of examples out there on internet. You will find even a tutorial with step by step on haw and why to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compact way:

```
struct Node
{
    int x;
    Node *next;
} nodes[] = {
    {1, nodes + 1},
    {2, nodes + 2},
    {3, nodes + 3},
    {4, nodes + 4},
    {5, nodes + 5},
    {6, nodes + 6},
    {7, nodes + 7},
    {8, nodes + 8},
    {9, nullptr}
};
Node* root = nodes;
```